# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.binarystore.project1.vendor_details.Vendor_Details$1

Tags: android

My code is execute and working fine in Android emulator in android studio but not working in my smartphone which i connected with my PC and USB debugging is enabled. I am getting this Exception.

Module:app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.binarystore.project1"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'



testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile project(':customfont')
}
```

Error:

```
 05-03 16:05:05.480 26599-26599/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.example.binarystore.project1, PID: 26599
                                               java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.binarystore.project1.vendor_details.Vendor_Details$1
                                                   at com.example.binarystore.project1.vendor_details.Vendor_Details.addActionListner(Vendor_Details.java:71)``
                                                   at com.example.binarystore.project1.vendor_details.Vendor_Details.onCreate(Vendor_Details.java:46)
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code:

```
public class Vendor_Details extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
CustomSwipeAdaptor adaptor;
ViewPager vp;
LinearLayout next, cook1, restaurant1, laundry1, room_deliver1, gym1, cook2, restaurant2, laundry2, room_deliver2, innerLay;
HorizontalScrollView hsv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.vendor_details_page);

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map_view);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    addImageViewpagerListner();
    addActionListner();`Error showing in this line and `
}

private void addImageViewpagerListner() {
    vp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    adaptor = new CustomSwipeAdaptor(this);
    vp.setAdapter(adaptor);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void addActionListner() {
    next = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.next);
    innerLay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.innerLay);
    cook1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.cook1);
    restaurant1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.restaurant1);
    laundry1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.laundry1);
    room_deliver1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.room_deliver1);
    gym1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.gym1);
    cook2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.cook2);
    restaurant2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.restaurant2);
    laundry2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.laundry2);
    room_deliver2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.room_deliver2);

    hsv = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.hs_view);

    hsv.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {`Error showing this line`
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
            View view = (View) hsv.getChildAt(hsv.getChildCount() - 1);
            int diff = (view.getRight() - (hsv.getWidth() + hsv.getScrollX()));
            if (diff <= 0) {
                next.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                next.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    try {
        // Customise the styling of the base map using a JSON object defined
        // in a raw resource file.
        boolean success = googleMap.setMapStyle(
                MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                        this, R.raw.map_style_night));
        if (!success) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Style parsing failed.");
        }
    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Can't find style. Error: ", e);
    }
    LatLng ind = new LatLng(20, 78);
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(ind));
}
```

}

Comment: Please, provide API versions for your emulator and phone. Also ensure, that your phone has Google Play Services installed.

Comment: my app API :
compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.binarystore.project1"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
My mobile API is :
android 4.4.2---API level 19

Answer (score 0):

### First variant

Your problem is caused by wrong use of multidex. So your app will work normally for API 21+ , and will cause `NoClassDefFoundError` for lower APIs.

You have this in your build.gradle file

```
defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.example.binarystore.project1"
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 25
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
multiDexEnabled true
testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

You see, `multiDexEnabled true` option will work only for API 21+, and for older APIs you need to include this line `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` in your dependencies. And also add this code to your application code

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
 super.attachBaseContext(base);
 MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

For details about using multidex look [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html).

### Second variant

You are callin method that is declared with @TargetApi(..M) annotation on phone, that doesn't match version requirements. Add version check to your code and either call another method, or call nothing.
Looking at line, that gives you error you can find "setOnScrollChangeListener" method, that was introduced only in 23 API, when you are trying to use it on 19. [Method refference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnScrollChangeListener(android.view.View.OnScrollChangeListener)).

And I advise you not to use `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:....'` because it will add all play-services to your project and dramatically increase your codebase and app size. Try add only modules that you'r using. Read [this](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) article for further details

Answer (score 0):

use `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` inside dependency